# Wget cuts end of URL

Tags: url, wget

I try to download the HTML result of the URL "https://www.ep-infonet.de/apps/de-DE?layout=v6#/app/bestellbestand_index/de-DE?tabelle=fakturen&phase=fakturen".
My command is:

```
"wget --load-cookies cookies.txt "https://www.ep-infonet.de/apps/de-DE?layout=v6#/app/bestellbestand_index/de-DE?tabelle=fakturen&phase=fakturen"
```

But if I run this, it only saves this file: "de-DE?layout=v6.2". I wondered if it cuts at the #  because it means comment in bash? How can I make wget load the URL properly?
(The site I want to load is only accessable with the cookies.txt I got, hope you can halp me anyway)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. I had to use URL encoding and replace the # with %23.

Answer (score 0):

Content in a URL past the `#` (that is, the *fragment identifier*) isn't sent to the web server in the request. It's interpreted by the browser, either it's an element ID to jump to in the page, or it's used by Javascript code. (In this case, it's probably the latter.)

The page you're trying to download probably uses Javascript to dynamically load and update content. You won't be able to download it using `wget` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the content of the file **de-DE?layout=v6.2?** I don't have the **cookies.txt**, but when I type the url in **wget** or in my **browser** and do view source the contents are the same.

I usually find with wget on a large url with lots of special characters, it does this but the content is correct. For these long urls I just get the habit of adding the **-O flag and set the file name myself**.

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt "https://www.ep-infonet.de/apps/de-DE?layout=v6#/app/bestellbestand_index/de-DE?tabelle=fakturen&phase=fakturen" -O myfile.txt
```